# Object shows property with data; property shows up blank

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting a pretty confusing result, and not sure what's going on. I suspect this is a strictly Javascript issue, but I'm not what.

I have a `CanActivate` guard in which I'm trying to retrieve data from the route resolver.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    this.userService.watchCurrentUser().subscribe((currentUser: User) => {
        console.log(route, route.data);
    });
    return Observable.of(true);
}
```

The data shows up as follows:

```
ActivatedRouteSnapshot {url: Array(2), params: Object, queryParams: Object, fragment: null, data: Object…} Object {}
```

Though it's a bit hard to see, you can see the data object exists within the snapshot, and if I expand it, it has all the data I expect. However, you can also see that when I log `route.data`, the object is blank. I can't figure out why and I don't know how to debug why.

Comment: have you tried to expand the seemingly blank object?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I said it's blank because it is an actually empty object. Expanded, it just contains prototype, as any empty object does.

Answer (score 0):

Data is an object that you defined statically in route configuration. For example, I use title in the data obj to dynamically show page title depends on route and each route has its own data object.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'path',
  component: ContainerComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: {title: 'My Chart'}
 },
 ....
]
```

Comment: As I mentioned, when I log route, the data property contains the values I expect. When I log route.data, it comes up as an empty object.